# What are pump probe measurements?

Tags: laser, terminology, optics

I was in class today, and we had a presentation by a student on how tunable lasers are used in fiber optics and change the wavelength. He also explained that by "pump probe measurements" a "sample gets excited and can be measured over time".

Can anyone explain what this means? What is a "sample"? How are "pump probe measurements" useful when dealing with tunable lasers?

Comment: You should rather ask this question at http://physics.stackexchange.com/ .

Comment: @starblue That is a good point. I asked a fiber optics question there last time, and no one answered. Where does the topic of fiber optics belong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [Encyclopedia of Laser Physics and Technology](http://www.rp-photonics.com/pump_probe_measurements.html):

> Pump–probe measurements can be used to obtain information on ultrafast
>   phenomena. The general principle is the following. A sample (e.g. a
>   SESAM) is hit by some pump pulse, which generates some kind of
>   excitation (or other modification) in the sample. After an adjustable
>   time delay (controlled with an optical delay line), a probe pulse hits
>   the sample, and its transmission or reflection is measured. By
>   monitoring the probe signal as a function of the time delay, it is
>   possible to obtain information on the decay of the generated
>   excitation, or on other processes initiated by the pump pulses.

From the Wikipedia article on [Time-resolved spectroscopy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time-resolved_spectroscopy):

> Transient-absorption spectroscopy is an extension of absorption
>   spectroscopy. Here, the absorbance at a particular wavelength or range
>   of wavelengths of a sample is measured as a function of time after
>   excitation by a flash of light. In a typical experiment, both the
>   light for excitation ('pump') and the light for measuring the
>   absorbance ('probe') are generated by a pulsed laser.

The "sample" is anything that you want to get the [spectrogram](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectrogram) of.

[This article](http://www.photonics.com/Article.aspx?AID=25043) mentions photochemistry as one possible application. It also notes that:

> in some applications such as spectroscopy and pump-probe experiments,
>   the laser wavelength must be tuned continuously during the experiment
>   or test.

So, it's not that pump-probe measurements are useful when dealing with tunable lasers, its that tunable lasers are useful when dealing with pump-probe measurements.